# Facebook SDK - Getting all users that use the application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I don't know what you guys think, but I believe that the Facebook SDK documentation is very limited and doesn't explain very much; Luckily throughout the use of some videos I was able to set up most of the integration that I needed.

However my application doesn't interact with just Facebook friends. It interacts with anyone and everyone using the application. Meaning if Jim and Sally aren't facebook friends, they can still see each-others profile picture, age, and name.

I'm not asking for you guys to write this out for me, but a nudge in the right direction would be lovely, perhaps accompanied by a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to "get all App users", you would have to store each user in your own database. Of course you have to deal with users deauthorizing your App - you can do that with the "Deauthorize Callback URL" in the advanced settings of your App.

Comment: What would be the best way to store these users, via the face-book id? I already have a database for my users (Because I was using a regular login system before hand) and I'm still trying to figure out how to tie facebook into that. If I store a user through their facebook id, can I get their information based off of it? Thanks.

Comment: yes, the best way is to store their id, of course. it´s the only thing that identifies the user correctly and it never changes in an app. you can get their info right when they authorize your app: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login